# How can I create a frequency table with two categorical variables?

Tags: r, datatable, categorical-data

I have the following dataset and am trying to have the row as the word (i.e. rely, trust) and the column as the colour with counts for each word/color combination.

I've tried this but for one of the word categories "fun" some colors were not voted so they have no data and appear blank in a table.

If anyone knows how I could process this data and fill in the blanks that would be an immense help!

```
    > goodcol
      rely  trust secure  speed    fun quality   tech  brave mostFav
1    White  White   Blue   Grey Yellow   Black  Black  White    Blue
2    White Yellow   Blue    Red Yellow   Black  Black Purple     Red
3     Blue  Green   Grey    Red Purple   Black   Blue    Red     Red
4    Black   Grey   Grey    Red Orange   Black   Blue   Blue   Black
5    Black  Green   Blue    Red Orange   Black  Black Purple    Blue
6    Black Purple  White    Red   Blue   Black   Grey Purple   Black
7     Blue   Blue  Green    Red Orange   Green   Blue Purple  Purple
8     Blue   Blue  Green    Red Purple    Grey   Grey Purple    Blue
9     Blue   Grey  Black Yellow Orange  Purple  Brown Purple  Orange
10    Grey   Blue   Blue    Red Yellow    Grey  Black Purple   White
11    Blue  White    Red Yellow Purple    Blue  Black Purple   Green
12    Blue  Brown  White    Red Yellow   Black   Blue   Blue   Green
13   Black   Grey    Red  Green Yellow    Blue   Blue   Blue    Blue
14    Blue Yellow    Red    Red Orange   Green   Grey Purple    Blue
15  Yellow   Blue  Brown    Red Orange   Green Yellow    Red    Blue
16   Green  White  Green Yellow Orange    Blue   Grey Purple    Blue
17    Blue   Blue    Red  Green    Red  Yellow Yellow Purple   Brown
18  Purple Yellow   Blue    Red  Green   White  White Purple    Blue
19   Black  White   Blue    Red  Green   Black   Blue    Red    Blue
20   Black   Blue  Black    Red Orange   Black   Grey    Red   Black
21   Black  Black    Red    Red Yellow    Grey   Grey   Blue    Blue
22    Grey   Blue   Blue    Red Orange   Black  White  Black    Blue
23   Green  White   Blue    Red    Red  Purple  Brown    Red    Blue
24    Blue   Blue   Grey    Red Orange   White  Black Purple    Blue
25    Blue  White   Blue    Red Yellow    Blue  Black Purple    Blue
26  Purple Purple Purple    Red    Red   Black  Black Purple  Purple
27     Red   Grey Purple  Brown  White  Orange Yellow    Red   White
28    Blue    Red  Green  White Orange    Blue  Green    Red   Black
29   Black   Blue Yellow  Black Yellow    Grey Yellow    Red     Red
30    Blue Purple  Green    Red Orange    Grey Purple  Green  Purple
31   Black  Brown   Blue    Red Purple   Green    Red    Red  Purple
32   Green   Blue  Black    Red    Red   Black   Blue  White   Green
33    Blue Yellow    Red  Black Orange   White   Grey Purple  Yellow
34    Blue Yellow  Green    Red   Blue   Green  Green  White   Green
35   Black   Blue    Red    Red Yellow   Black  Black  White    Blue
36    Blue   Blue  White    Red Purple    Blue Yellow    Red    Blue
37    Blue   Blue  Black Yellow    Red    Grey Purple   Blue    Blue
38    Grey   Blue    Red Yellow Orange    Blue  Black    Red  Orange
39    Blue Purple  Black    Red Orange    Grey   Grey    Red  Purple
40   Green Orange  Green Orange Orange    Grey   Blue Orange    Blue
41     Red    Red Orange  Green  Green    Blue   Blue  White     Red
42    Blue Purple Purple    Red Orange   Black  Black   Blue   Green
43   Black  Green  Black    Red    Red   White   Grey  White    Blue
44   Green  Green   Blue    Red Orange   Black   Grey Purple  Orange
45    Grey  Green   Blue    Red    Red  Purple   Blue    Red  Purple
46    Blue   Blue  White    Red Yellow   Black   Grey   Blue  Purple
47   Black  White  Black   Blue Yellow    Blue   Blue   Blue     Red
48   Black   Blue Purple    Red Yellow   Black  Black    Red  Purple
49   Black  Black    Red    Red Yellow   Green   Blue   Blue  Purple
50   Black  White   Blue    Red Orange  Purple  Black Yellow  Purple
51    Blue    Red   Blue    Red Purple   White  Black    Red   Green
52    Blue Purple  Green    Red    Red    Blue   Grey    Red    Blue
53    Blue Purple   Blue Purple Orange   Black  Black    Red    Blue
54    Grey   Blue  Black Yellow Orange   Black   Blue   Blue    Grey
55   Black   Blue  Black    Red Purple   Black  Black Purple     Red
56  Purple Purple Purple    Red    Red   Black  Black Purple  Purple
57    Grey   Blue   Blue    Red Orange    Grey   Grey   Grey   Green
58   Black   Blue Orange  White Yellow    Grey  White  Brown    Blue
59    Blue  White Yellow    Red Yellow   Black  Black Purple     Red
60   Black  White   Blue Yellow    Red     Red  Green Purple    Blue
61    Blue    Red  Green    Red Purple    Grey  White   Blue     Red
62    Grey   Blue    Red    Red Orange    Blue   Blue   Blue   Black
63   Black    Red   Blue  White Purple   Black  Black Purple    Blue
64    Blue   Blue Purple Orange Orange   Black   Blue    Red    Blue
65   White Purple  Brown    Red  Green    Blue   Blue   Blue   Green
66    Blue   Blue  Black    Red Purple   Black  Black Purple  Purple
67   Black  White   Blue    Red    Red  Purple  Green Purple    Blue
68    Blue  Green    Red  Green  Green    Blue   Blue  Black    Blue
69   Black   Blue  Black    Red Yellow   Black   Grey   Blue    Blue
70     Red Purple  Green    Red Purple   Green   Grey   Blue   Green
71    Blue  White    Red    Red Yellow   Black  Black  Brown    Blue
72    Blue  Green    Red Orange  Green    Blue   Blue Purple   Green
73    Blue   Blue   Blue    Red Purple   Black   Grey  Black   Green
74    Blue   Blue   Blue    Red Yellow   Black  Black   Blue  Purple
75   White  White    Red  White Purple   White   Blue   Blue   White
76    Blue   Blue  White Yellow    Red   Black  White Purple     Red
77    Blue  White  Brown    Red   Blue   White   Grey   Blue    Blue
78     Red    Red   Blue   Grey Orange   White   Grey Purple    Grey
79   Black   Blue   Blue    Red    Red   Black  Black    Red    Blue
80   Black  White  White    Red   Blue   Black   Blue   Blue   Brown
81    Blue Purple  Green    Red Yellow   Black  Black Purple   Black
82    Blue Purple   Blue    Red Orange   Black   Blue   Blue    Blue
83   Black  White   Blue    Red Yellow   Black  White    Red   Black
84   White  White  Black    Red Yellow  Yellow   Blue    Red    Grey
85    Blue  White   Blue    Red Yellow   Black   Grey    Red    Blue
86   Brown  White   Grey    Red   Blue   Black  Green   Blue   Green
87   Black    Red   Blue    Red Purple   Black  White   Blue  Purple
88    Blue Purple   Blue  Black  Green   Black   Blue    Red  Purple
89    Blue  White  Black    Red Yellow   Black   Blue Purple    Blue
90    Blue   Blue  Brown Yellow Orange    Grey   Grey   Blue    Blue
91    Blue  Black    Red    Red Yellow    Blue    Red   Blue    Blue
92    Blue   Blue   Blue    Red Orange   Black   Grey Purple  Purple
93    Blue   Blue   Blue    Red    Red   Brown  Black  White    Blue
94    Grey   Blue  Brown    Red Yellow  Purple  White Purple   Green
95   Black  White   Blue    Red Orange    Grey   Grey   Blue    Blue
96    Blue   Blue   Blue    Red    Red   White   Blue   Blue   Black
97    Blue   Blue   Blue    Red Purple   White  White Orange    Blue
98  Purple   Blue  Green  Black Orange    Blue  Black Purple   Green
99    Grey  Brown  Brown    Red Orange    Grey   Grey Purple    Blue
100   Blue  Black  Black  Green Orange   White   Blue   Blue    Blue
101  White    Red  White    Red Orange   Black   Grey    Red  Orange
102   Grey  Green   Blue    Red    Red   Black  White   Blue   Black
103  Brown    Red   Blue    Red    Red   Black  Black Yellow     Red
104   Blue  Brown   Grey Orange Purple   Black   Grey    Red    Grey
105  Brown   Blue  Brown    Red Orange   Black  Black    Red    Blue
106  Black   Blue  Black    Red  White    Blue   Blue  Black    Blue
107   Blue    Red  Black    Red Orange   White  White Purple    Blue
108  Brown   Blue    Red  White Orange   Black  Black    Red  Orange
109 Yellow  Black  Black    Red  White   Green  Brown  Green   Brown
110 Yellow  Green  White    Red    Red     Red  Black    Red    Blue
111   Blue Purple Purple    Red Yellow   White  Black    Red   Green
```

Comment: Could you perhaps provide the data in a usable format (e.g. using `dput()`and specify your `data.frame` as argument)? It's easier to help you if you include ready-made data, so that we can use it to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If certain colors are not present in a column you can use them as factor with levels that has all the colors available in the data.

```
all_vals <- unique(unlist(goodcol))
res <- t(sapply(goodcol, function(x) table(factor(x, all_vals))))
res

#        White Blue Black Grey Yellow Green Purple Red Brown Orange
#rely        6   48    27   10      3     5      4   4     4      0
#trust      21   38     5    4      5     9     14  10     4      1
#secure      8   35    17    5      2    12      7  16     7      2
#speed       5    1     4    2      9     5      1  79     1      4
#fun         3    5     0    0     26     7     16  18     0     36
#quality    13   17    47   14      2     8      6   2     1      1
#tech       11   27    31   25      5     5      2   2     3      0
#brave       7   28     4    1      2     2     34  29     2      2
#mostFav     3   45     9    4      1    15     16  10     3      5
```

Answer (score 0):

using dplyr and tidyr

```
dat2 %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = "word") %>%
    group_by(word, value) %>%
    summarize(Count = n()) %>%
    pivot_wider(id_cols = word, names_from = value, values_from = Count,
                values_fill = 0)
```

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldPSD.png)